# Compare two words

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-word, nasm

How to compare two words in NASM assembly? consider this code:

```
global start
start:
    mov eax,array
    mov edx,4
    mov ecx,2987074
.LOOP1:
    cmp word [eax],ecx
    je .FOUND
    add eax,4
    sub edx,1
    jz .NOTFOUND
    jmp .LOOP1
.FOUND:
    xor ebx,ebx
    jmp .EXIT
.NOTFOUND:
    mov ebx,1
.EXIT:
    mov eax,1
    int 0x80

array:  
    dd 1137620
    dd 3529469
    dd 2987074
    dd 1111111
    dd 2222222
```

returns

> foo.asm:7: error: mismatch in operand sizes

and changing cmp from `cmp word [eax],ecx` to `cmp word [eax],word ecx`

returns:

```
foo.asm:7: warning: register size specification ignored
foo.asm:7: error: mismatch in operand sizes
```

I have no idea how to fix this. Can someone explain it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmp word [eax],ecx` is wrong because operand sizes don't match (`ecx` is a `dword`, not `word`). Most x86 instructions with two operands can only work with operands of the same size.

`cmp word [eax],word ecx` is wrong because `ecx` is a `dword`, not `word`.

If you're coming from the `(g)as`/`gcc` world, it's worth noting that their `.word` is the machine word and on a 32-bit machine it's 32-bit. NASM's `word` is always 16-bit and its `dword` is always 32-bit.

You probably want just `cmp [eax], ecx`. Since the two operands of `cmp` must be of the same size, NASM deduces here that the memory operand at address in `eax` is the same size as the register operand `ecx`, 32-bit (`dword`).

Comment: Thanks you again. I was thinking that without an explicit(try) data type size definition will be I have a `dword` instead of `word` or `byte` instead of `dword`(in some cases) for this reason I did `cmp word [eax],word ecx` instead of `cmp [eax],ecx` it really work. Thank you again.